# Pointer to table of string

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

I'm creating a proof of work of a DNS Tunneling and everything is working with 64 bytes long domain names. As I want to make Ping over DNS, I need to create fragments and to use my program with fragments.
All my fragments are in a table that i use in a function : `char (*frag)[][48]` (48 bytes long because the domain is 16 bytes long)

Then I have changed my send DNS Request packet to iterate over each fragment in the frag packet. Therefore I want to pass as argument of the function:

- A pointer to an array which is a string represented as an array : the dns query
- A pointer to an array of fragment

My working program edit the DNS Request like this :

```
    unsigned char *nom_query = &buffer_dns[k][sizeof(struct DNS_HEADER)];
```

In my program, I want to have in argument of my function a pointer to an array which contain strings represented in a table.
I have think about this :

`char (*buffer_dns)[]`

But I can't iterate and do this

```
&(*buffer_dns)[i][sizeof(struct DNS_HEADER)]
```

Is the correct sentence ?

`char (*buffer_dns)[][]`

I understand the writing :

`char (*buffer_dns)[]`
but i don't understand this one
`char (*buffer_dns)[][]`

If someone can explain this :)

Thank you very much

Comment: Some context is needed. Particularly: are the strings all of individual lengths or is it a 2D array with everything at a fixed maximum length? How do you allocate the strings? Also why does the title say C#?

Comment: I've added some context and I have max length for fragment but not for DNS Buffer

Comment: `[][]` can never be correct.

Comment: So i need to set a size for one of them ?

Comment: The size can only be omitted on the leftmost `[]`. The function parameter for accessing a 2D array of `char` could be declared as `char (*buffer_dns)[sizeof(struct DNS_HEADER)]`.

Comment: ok thank you I've succeeded with your advices